# core dumped,but I don't find the error location,there have the GDB's error infomation

Tags: c++, linux, arangodb, .so

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000340f87a31f in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.4-5.el6.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.x86_64 libcom_err-1.41.12-22.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-7.el6.x86_64 libuuid-2.17.2-12.24.el6.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6_8.1.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000340f87a31f in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000340f87abfc in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004a913b in UDataMemory_createNewInstance_54 ()
#3  0x00000000004a7ac7 in doLoadFromCommonData(signed char, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, signed char (*)(void*, char const*, char const*, UDataInfo const*), void*, UErrorCode*, UErrorCode*) ()
#4  0x00000000004a89cb in doOpenChoice(char const*, char const*, char const*, signed char (*)(void*, char const*, char const*, UDataInfo const*), void*, UErrorCode*) ()
#5  0x000000000045febd in icu_54::CollationRoot::load(UErrorCode&) ()
#6  0x000000000045ffe8 in icu_54::CollationRoot::getRootCacheEntry(UErrorCode&) ()
#7  0x000000000044b29a in icu_54::CollationLoader::loadTailoring(icu_54::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) ()
#8  0x000000000042d668 in icu_54::Collator::createInstance(icu_54::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) ()
#9  0x0000000000412691 in triagens::basics::Utf8Helper::setCollatorLanguage(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#10 0x00000000004120aa in triagens::basics::Utf8Helper::Utf8Helper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#11 0x00000000004120ed in triagens::basics::Utf8Helper::Utf8Helper() ()
#12 0x0000000000414ac0 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 ()
#13 0x0000000000414ae9 in _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN8triagens6basics10Utf8Helper17DefaultUtf8HelperE ()
#14 0x000000000050d5e6 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#15 0x00000000004085cb in _init ()
#16 0x00007fc223318068 in boost::system::native_ecat () from /home/workspace/DLL_CPPServer/Debug/libDLL_CPPServer.so
#17 0x000000000050d525 in __libc_csu_init ()
#18 0x000000340f81ecb0 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

above codes is the GDB Infomation; the `triagens::basics::Utf8Helper::Utf8Helper()` was not called my codes.first,I think it called by the 3rdParty library and the method exist in 3rdparty's source;But I don't find it was used when I search the `utf8Helper` key. 
  so I didn't know the reason,can you help me?

Comment: Core dump all the way down in malloc => you've most likely corrupted your heap. Use valgrind or sanitizers to see if they spot issues.

Comment: When you have crashes in `malloc` the reason is most likely that you have some out-of-bounds problems, probably writing outside of allocated memory. Use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find such problems.

Comment: I download the Valgrind，and use it to debug.But the error message is similiar to the GDB's INFO;  there is still not the error location info;

Comment: You code is not directly calling the method.  The crash is happening during static object initialization.  Is that call part of the ArangoDB library?  If so, one strategy is to write a simple test driver and see if the call still fails.  If so, then it is a bug or more likely some configuration problem.  Must more likely however is the some static ctor or your is corrupting the heap.  Do you have any static objects?  Did valgrind give an message about bad memory write, double free or other heap related errors? If so, that will be the spot to look

Comment: @MatthewFisher  thank you.yes,the 3rdparty is ArangoDB and ActiveMQ,now the error produced by ArangoDB.The dirver is ok through by my test.  That so weirdly that I don't define a global/static object from arangodb,just use the 'thread' class from arangodb,and in there,I don't find problem.

Comment: Did the test driver make the same call?  You can put a breakpoint on doLoadFromCommonData to see. Do you have an idea of what is being loaded?  Maybe there is some configuration issue that is exposing a bug.  As another option, gcc has the environment variables MALLOC_CHECK_  for heap checking.  Export the variable in your environment and try running.

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewFisher  hm. I set a breakpoint on doLoadFromCommonData,but it doesn't work,the program didn't join it. I use ' export MALLOC_CHECK_=2 ' and ' ./test ' ,it generate a core.4675. Use ' gdb ./test core.4675 ' ,' where ' produced one passage:

```
`Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000340f876009 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x000000340f876009 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.4-5.el6.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.x86_64 libcom_err-1.41.12-22.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-7.el6.x86_64 libuuid-2.17.2-12.24.el6.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6_8.1.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000340f876009 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000340f879d08 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000340f87c538 in malloc_check () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000340f87ab31 in calloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x000000340f835ca4 in __new_exitfn () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000340f835d58 in __cxa_atexit_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x000000000041f1c9 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 ()
#7  0x000000000041f238 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_TRI_prioritynames ()
#8  0x000000000050d5e6 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#9  0x00000000004085cb in _init ()
#10 0x00007f7f1dc5a068 in boost::system::native_ecat () from /home/workspace/DLL_CPPServer/Debug/libDLL_CPPServer.so
#11 0x000000000050d525 in __libc_csu_init ()
#12 0x000000340f81ecb0 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#13 0x0000000000409449 in _start ()`
```

Comment: @MatthewFisher   this passage diffrent from the origin question's error-code

Comment: Heap corruption can cause the crash to happen at different spots.  Try to minimize the number of libraries that are linked in and then run again.  Hopefully, you can narrow down the area of the crash.  Careful check  any new/malloc handling in your code in static objects or functions.  Usually 3rd party libraries are better tested than custom code so the problem is more likely to be in your code.

Comment: hm,thank you ,I according to your sugestion to test.When I Split my project and test minimize,I found a weird error: " when I use a string constants like "hello" to transfer paramenter to a type of 'string',it always error that segmentation fault ". And I don't know how to test the arangodb's library .

Comment: When I not use Arangodb's library,my test was work good,when I quote ArangoDB's library ,it make falut as my error info topside at this question.      but use the ArangoDB's library siglely test,it's not any problem,so weird!

Comment: What does the code and stack look like for the parameter seg fault?   Did you try the minimized  driver under valgrind?

Comment: yes,The fault caused by the 'string' paramenter and I give it a constants string like 'hello',it's so weird,I think that there's nothing wrong..Ok,I will try the valgrind

Comment: Maybe post some of the code.  When converting between strings and char * temporaries can be created, sometimes that can cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is the code :

```
CompletePortLogFile::CCompletePortLogFile(string sFullPath)
{
        _sFullPath = sFullPath;
        InitializeCriticalSection(&_freeStackLock);
        InitializeCriticalSection(&_fileLock);
        _hFile = NULL;
        _hCompletePort = NULL;
        _nTotalSize = 0;
        _nPackageNo = 0;
}


if(NULL==g_pLogFile)
{
        g_pLogFile = new IOTP::CCompletePortLogFile(".\\CPPServer.log");
        g_pLogFile->init();
}
```

There is the GDB's Error Info :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000340f87a31f in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000340f87a31f in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000340f87abfc in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003e8005e808 in operator new(unsigned long) ()
    at ../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:49
#3  0x0000003e800c3c49 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
    at /home/hewei/download/gcc-build-4.9.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h:104
#4  0x0000003e800c55c5 in char* std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) ()
    at /home/hewei/download/gcc-build-4.9.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:138
#5  0x0000003e800c59f6 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
    at /home/hewei/download/gcc-build-4.9.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1743
#6  0x00007ffff7dd12e3 in iotp_initGlobalLogFile() () at ../src/main/ActivemqServer.cpp:62
#7  0x00007ffff7dd13bf in iotp_GetLibraryInstance () at ../src/main/ActivemqServer.cpp:71
#8  0x000000000040147b in testDLL(char*) ()
#9  0x00000000004016a2 in main ()
```